# vb net + getting content from a div with htmlagilitypack

Tags: json, vb.net, html-agility-pack

Flow:
1. (OK) i download a json
2. (OK) i parse a value from the json object that contains html
3. (NOT OK) i display the values inside div.countries

my code:

```
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://example.com/countries.json")
Dim values As JObject = JObject.Parse(result)
Dim finalHTML As String = values.GetValue("countries_html")
```

basically finalHTML variable looks like this:

```
<div class="country_name">USA</div>
<div class="country_name">Ireland</div>
<div class="country_name">Australia</div>
```

Im stuck and dont know how to move on.
I need to go over all div.country_name and get the inner_text of it. Hope that make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `finalHTML` string already contain only the target div elements, you can simply load the string to `HtmlDocument` object and use a bit of LINQ to project the divs into collection -`IEnumerable`, `List<T>`, or whatever most suitable to your need- of InnerText strings :

```
....
Dim finalHTML As String = values.GetValue("countries_html")
Dim doc = New HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml(finalHTML)
Dim countries = doc.DocumentNode.Elements("div").Select(Function(o) o.InnerText.Trim())

'print the result as comma separated text to console:
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", countries))
```

**<kbd>[`Dotnetfiddle Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5ihnru)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
USA,Ireland,Australia
```

Comment: never knew there is dot net fiddle, wow! and of course, thank you so much for your solution - it helped me a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

here's a nice article on using the HAP: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/273/using-the-htmlagilitypack-to-parse-html-in-asp-net.